# detect android hybrid app environment in website

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, hybrid-mobile-app

I have to turn my web page into a hybrid app, designed a webpage but in app i dont want some features! is there any way to execute some CSS by detecting that we are using app or browser?

i got some code this can detect browsers, im not sure about app!

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
 ....code 
 $('#test').css("margin-top","10%");
}
if ($.browser.webkit) {
code goes here
}
if ($.browser.mozilla) {
code goes here
}
```

not responsive method! i need responsive website in browser but i need to hide some features like nav bar, footer etc in app!

any possible way by using JS or JQuery and CSS?

please help me with it!

Comment: do you have access to Android app code and can you change it?

Answer (score 0):

Your web site will always be executed in a browser or view of html page, so you can not access these settings directly, but if you want to create an app for the store, you can use [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) or PhoneGap to package your web site and you will have access to navbar masking and several other settings reserved for native applications.